# What might be reason for less than actual row counts in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV file which has 41858 lines viewed in VIM editor. However, when I use the following code to read it to a pandas Dataframe, the line count becomes 40615:

```
column_type = {'sense': 'int'}
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', dtype=column_type)
```

I dont' do any modifications to the dataframe at these two simple lines. I observed the row count through PyCharm's debugger.

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: Do any of the lines have text strings that might be split across lines?  You're allowed to have embedded newlines in a quoted field.

Comment: @TimRoberts It's a big file with over 40000 rows, so I don't know whether there are such lines.

Comment: @Prune It's hard to know where the problem is, so I have to provide the entire file for your testing. To create a minimal reproducible example is hard without where the issue is.

Comment: We expect that you will trace the suspect values just before the point of error.  See this lovely reference for [debugging help](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs).

Comment: "It's hard to know" ... yes, it's quite hard when you won't do the initial work to isolate or narrow down the problem.  So far, you have declined to post enough code to reproduce the problem, to provide a minimal data set, or even to examine the data for simple characteristics.  Any of these disqualifies this as a viable Stack Overflow question.  Just what interaction do you expect from us?

Comment: Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.